# Non-readable POM (Permission denied) when running build in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

Using MAC os.When I try to run a new build for test project in Jenkins, I got this error in the console:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
12:32:26 [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while 
processing the POMs:
12:32:26 [FATAL] Non-readable POM 
/Users/****/pom.xml: 
/Users/****/pom.xml 
(Permission denied) @
```

I give my pom.xml file permissions 777. Here is my POM.xml, which consist of the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>HybridMavenProject</groupId>
<artifactId>Learning_Selenium</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
 </build>
 <dependencies>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Also in Jenkins for the Build I give exact path for my POM

Comment: Check permissions of pom.xml file.

Comment: how to that. I'm using MAC

Comment: Open terminal. cd to directory where your POM file is. And type ls -l command.

Comment: -rw-r--r--   1 MY_USERNAME  staff  1435 Oct  4 14:16 pom.xml

Comment: Try to give execute permission as well. sudo chmod 777 <pom.xml>

Comment: Did that, but still got this error: https://ibb.co/mt0edw

Comment: Can you post the contents of your pom file?

Comment: @RishikeshDarandale please see my POM file above in the description.

Comment: How do you copy this project to your jenkins job workspace? Is jenkins started by the same user as the file owner? Can you please check the workspace directory for your test jenkins project?

Comment: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Test this is the workspace created from Jenkins automatically. I didn't created by myself. The other questions I'm not sure what to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give 777 permission to jenkins jobs/workspace folder for USER: who is running jobs in Jenkins master/slave agent.

I have a similar error, where Jenkins is not able to parse pom.xml and create dir. as permission denied error, so i have checked /var/jenkins_home/JOBS folder in jenkins agent, so the permission to USER is read only, so i have given write and execute permission to that folder from root, and so i am able to build jobs.

Comment: Please do give some explanation!