# Jenkins Non-readable POM

Tags: java, jenkins, intellij-idea, junit

This error is posted in different forums even [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644233/non-readable-pom-permission-denied-when-running-build-in-jenkins). I have tried the different alternatives. I tried changing the POM permissions. I am using the default maven settings. JDK is 8, Maven 3.5.3.

I just want to try a very simple junit application. From the command line I have no problems running "mvn test"

```
junitexample amh$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< com.junit:junit-example >-----------------------
[INFO] Building junit-example 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ junit-example ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ junit-example ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ junit-example ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/amhg/Documents/dev/intellik2/junitexample/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ junit-example ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ junit-example ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/amhg/Documents/dev/intellik2/junitexample/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running CalculatorTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.045 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.178 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-08T01:39:52+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But from Jenkins, from the Console Output I have this error:

Console Output

```
Started by user Andrea
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/calc
[calc] $ /Users/amhg/apache-maven-3.5.3/bin/mvn -f /Users/amhg/Documents/dev/intellik2/junitexample test
POM file /Users/amhg/Documents/dev/intellik2/junitexample specified with the -f/--file command line argument does not exist
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-readable POM /Users/amhg/Documents/dev/intellik2/junitexample: /Users/amhg/Documents/dev/intellik2/junitexample (Permission denied) @ 
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project  (/Users/amhg/Documents/dev/intellik2/junitexample) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-readable POM /Users/amhg/Documents/dev/intellik2/junitexample: /Users/amhg/Documents/dev/intellik2/junitexample (Permission denied)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

This is my POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-example</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>junit-example</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And I just have a simple test:

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertEquals;

public class CalculatorTest {
    private static ICalculator calculator;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initCalculator() {
        calculator = new Calculator();

    }

    @Test
    public void testSum() {
        int result = calculator.sum(3, 4);
        assertEquals(7, result);
    }
}
```

I don´t know what else I could try. I opened all the topics related to the problem.

Any other suggestion?

Comment: Read the error message: `POM file ... does not exist`. You should be using `-f some/path/to/pom.xml`.

Comment: I should be using  -f some/path/to/pom.xml. You mean that I should add "-f ". I am on OS X, so I have this defined /Users/andrea/Documents/dev/example/pom.xml. I added -f at the beginning of the path. But still got an error

Comment: No, I mean that in the case of *the `-f` that you're already using*, as indicated by the error message, the proper argument is the POM file, not a directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had exact same problem - local maven build works and Jenkins fails with the same error as yours.

Once Jenkins job is started, it will import source code to `/your-jenkins/workspace/your-job-name` folder and then start building.  In your DSL, you have to mention the path to your pom in the workspace.

Take a look at the Jenkins workspace view to see where your pom is located once the source code is downloaded. This will aid in resolving the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the -f option you have provided. the maven is unable to identify the pom to read

> -f /Users/amhg/Documents/dev/intellik2/junitexample test

try giving in the complete name of the pom including .xml

> -f /Users/amhg/Documents/dev/intellik2/junitexample nameofpom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Please check what you have in your Jenkins Build -> Goals and in your Build -> POM.
You  probably switched those two.